# An error has occurred while importing data from *.csv file to PostgreSQL table

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, csv

I am trying to import data from *.csv file to PostgreSQL table but getting an error "extra data after last expected column". I checked complete csv file to debug the error but did not got an extra column or new line.

Here are the screenshots of procedure I have followed:

**Step 1**:

[image]

**Step 2**:

[image]

**Step 3**:

[image]

**Error Message**:

[image]

Comment: Please show us the table definition and a sample of the CSV file (the first two or three line) and ideally the `copy` command that was generated.

Comment: if table definition of table to import and table from import are same then you can simply use --------------- `COPY yourTable FROM 'absolute/path/to/file.csv' WITH CSV HEADER;`

Comment: @hector, Yeah! I did that but still getting error "invalid input syntax for integer". Because of this error I was trying from pgAdmin III which is shown above, using this I can provide quote for each column value and also escape.

Comment: @Meem i guess that both tables have exact same structure if so you try to export your table to `*.csv` file using `COPY(SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE) TO 'PATH/TO/SAVE/FILE.CSV' WITH CSV HEADER;`  and import the output file with the `COPY yourTable FROM 'absolute/path/to/file.csv' WITH CSV HEADER;`

Comment: @Meem post both tables `table definition`

Comment: @hector, I had exported SQL Server data into *.csv file. And now want to import that data into PostgreSQL table. And yes both tables structures are the same.

Comment: @Meem so your trying to `Data Migration` ????

Comment: @Meem have you read [this](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server_to_PostgreSQL_Migration_by_Ian_Harding) ??

Comment: @Creator, Yes! you are right.